# Couldn't understand CSS selectors meaning in the juizy slideshow stylesheet code

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to add the [juizy slideshow](http://www.creativejuiz.fr/trytotry/juizy-slideshow-full-css3-html5/) to my site page but i need to fully understand how it's made in order to synchronize its animations (slidings) with my own customs animations i would want add to the page as well.

In addition to the brief technical explanations in that first link, [here](http://www.creativejuiz.fr/blog/tutoriels/css3-creer-slideshow-automatique-controlable-transition) there are more details (but in french and the downladable code from *[1](http://www.creativejuiz.fr/trytotry/juizy-slideshow-full-css3-html5/) is slightly different of the discussed one as the author made some improvements on the downloadable version).

```
<body>

    <span id="sl_play" class="sl_command">&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="sl_pause" class="sl_command">&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="sl_i1" class="sl_command sl_i">&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="sl_i2" class="sl_command sl_i">&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="sl_i3" class="sl_command sl_i">&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="sl_i4" class="sl_command sl_i">&nbsp;</span>

    <section id="slideshow">

        <a class="commands prev commands1" href="#sl_i4" title="Go to last slide">&lt;</a>
        <a class="commands next commands1" href="#sl_i2" title="Go to 2nd slide">&gt;</a>
        <a class="commands prev commands2" href="#sl_i1" title="Go to 1rst slide">&lt;</a>
        <a class="commands next commands2" href="#sl_i3" title="Go to 3rd slide">&gt;</a>
        <a class="commands prev commands3" href="#sl_i2" title="Go to 2nd slide">&lt;</a>
        <a class="commands next commands3" href="#sl_i4" title="Go to 4th slide">&gt;</a>
        <a class="commands prev commands4" href="#sl_i3" title="Go to 3rd slide">&lt;</a>
        <a class="commands next commands4" href="#sl_i1" title="Go to first slide">&gt;</a>

        <a class="play_commands pause" href="#sl_pause" title="Maintain paused">Pause</a>
        <a class="play_commands play" href="#sl_play" title="Play the animation">Play</a>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="c_slider"></div>
            <div class="slider">
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/dummy-640x310-1.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
                    <figcaption>The mirror of soul</figcaption>
                </figure><!--
                --><figure>
                    <img src="img/dummy-640x310-2.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
                    <figcaption>Let's cross that bridge when we come to it</figcaption>
                </figure><!--
                --><figure>
                    <img src="img/dummy-640x310-3.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
                    <figcaption>Sushi<em>(do)</em> time</figcaption>
                </figure><!--
                --><figure>
                    <img src="img/dummy-640x310-4.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
                    <figcaption>Waking Life</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span id="timeline"></span>

        <ul class="dots_commands"><!--
            --><li><a title="Show slide 1" href="#sl_i1">Slide 1</a></li><!--
            --><li><a title="Show slide 2" href="#sl_i2">Slide 2</a></li><!--
            --><li><a title="Show slide 3" href="#sl_i3">Slide 3</a></li><!--
            --><li><a title="Show slide 4" href="#sl_i4">Slide 4</a></li>
        </ul>

    </section>

</body>
```

And this is the stylesheet code for it:

```
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    width: 640px;
    height: 310px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0 auto 2em;
    background: #FFF;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF 20%, #EEE 80%, #DDD);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF 20%, #EEE 80%, #DDD);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF 20%, #EEE 80%, #DDD);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF 20%, #EEE 80%, #DDD);
    background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF 20%, #EEE 80%, #DDD);

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}

/* Here are some other rules for the #timeline and .dots_commands that i removed to make shorter this code */

/* play/pause commands */
.play_commands {
    position: absolute;
    width: 22px; height: 22px;
    top: 25px; right: 25px;
    z-index: 10;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border:0 none;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, right 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, right 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s, right 1s;
}
.play { right: 55px; cursor: default; }

.pause:hover { border:0 none; }
.play_commands:focus { outline:0; }

#slideshow:hover .pause,
#sl_play:target ~ #slideshow:hover .pause,
.play_commands:focus {
    opacity: 1;
}
.sl_command:target ~ #slideshow:hover .pause,
#sl_pause:target ~ #slideshow:hover .pause {
    opacity: 0;
}
.pause:after,
.pause:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    top:0;
    width:38%;
    height: 22px;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.pause:after {
    right:0;
}
.pause:before {
    left:0;
}
.play {
    width: 1px; 
    height: 1px; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 20px solid #fff; 
    border-left: 20px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5); 
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    opacity: 0;
}
.play:hover,
.play:focus {
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}

#slideshow .container {
    position:relative;
    width: 640px;
    height: 310px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* timeline base */
#slideshow .container:after {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0; left:0;
    content: " ";
    background: #999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider {
    0%, 20%, 100%   { left: 0 }
    25%, 45%        { left: -100% }
    50%, 70%        { left: -200% }
    75%, 95%        { left: -300% }
}
@-moz-keyframes slider {
    0%, 20%, 100%   { left: 0 }
    25%, 45%        { left: -100% }
    50%, 70%        { left: -200% }
    75%, 95%        { left: -300% }
}
@keyframes slider {
    0%, 20%, 100%   { left: 0 }
    25%, 45%        { left: -100% }
    50%, 70%        { left: -200% }
    75%, 95%        { left: -300% }
}

#slideshow .slider {
    position: absolute;
    left:0; top:0;
    width: 400%;
    height: 310px;

    -webkit-animation: slider 32s infinite;
    -moz-animation: slider 32s infinite;
    animation: slider 32s infinite;
}
.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .slider {
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    -moz-transition: left 1s;
    transition: left 1s;
}
.sl_command:target ~ #slideshow .slider {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
#slideshow .c_slider {
    position: absolute;
    left:0; top:0;
    width: 400%;
    height: 310px;
    background: url(img/dummy-640x310-1.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat, url(img/dummy-640x310-2.jpg) 640px 0 no-repeat, url(img/dummy-640x310-3.jpg) 1280px 0 no-repeat, url(img/dummy-640x310-4.jpg) 1920px 0 no-repeat;
}
.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .c_slider {
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    -moz-transition: background 1s;
    transition: background 1s;
}


/* need a stop ! */

/* actions when target ! */
.sl_command { display: none; }

.sl_command:target ~ #slideshow .slider,
.sl_command:target ~ #slideshow figure:after,
.sl_command:target ~ #slideshow figcaption,
.sl_command:target ~ #slideshow #timeline,
.sl_command:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:after {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

#sl_play:target ~ #slideshow .slider,
#sl_play:target ~ #slideshow figure:after,
#sl_play:target ~ #slideshow figcaption,
#sl_play:target ~ #slideshow #timeline,
#sl_play:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:after {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

.sl_command:target ~ #slideshow .pause  { opacity:0; }
.sl_command:target ~ #slideshow .play   { opacity:1; right: 25px; cursor: pointer; }
#sl_play:target ~ #slideshow .pause     { opacity:0; }
#sl_play:target ~ #slideshow .play      { opacity:0; right: 55px; cursor: default;}

.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .slider                                   { visibility: hidden }
.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .slider figcaption                        { visibility: hidden }
.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:after     { display:none; }
.sl_i:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:before    { display:block; }}

#sl_i1:target ~ #slideshow .commands                                { display: none; }
#sl_i1:target ~ #slideshow .commands1                               { display: block; }
#sl_i1:target ~ #slideshow .c_slider                                { background-position: 0 0, 640px 0, 1280px 0, 1920px 0; }
#sl_i1:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:before   { left:0; }

#sl_i2:target ~ #slideshow .commands                                { display: none; }
#sl_i2:target ~ #slideshow .commands2                               { display: block; }
#sl_i2:target ~ #slideshow .c_slider                                { background-position: -640px 0, 0 0, 640px 0, 1280px 0; }
#sl_i2:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:before   { left:18px; }

#sl_i3:target ~ #slideshow .commands                                { display: none; }
#sl_i3:target ~ #slideshow .commands3                               { display: block; }
#sl_i3:target ~ #slideshow .c_slider                                { background-position: -1280px 0, -640px 0, 0 0, 640px 0; }
#sl_i3:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:before   { left:36px; }

#sl_i4:target ~ #slideshow .commands                                { display: none; }
#sl_i4:target ~ #slideshow .commands4                               { display: block; }
#sl_i4:target ~ #slideshow .c_slider                                { background-position: -1920px 0, -1280px 0, -640px 0, 0 0; }
#sl_i4:target ~ #slideshow .dots_commands li:first-child a:before   { left:54px; }
```

The combinations of selectors i couldn't understand from the previous stylesheet lies on this rule :

```
#slideshow:hover .pause,
#sl_play:target ~ #slideshow:hover .pause,
.play_commands:focus {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

1. Does the first combination `#slideshow:hover .pause` translate to "Select all elements with the class name pause that are descendants of the element with an ID of slideshow"?
2. What does `#sl_play:target ~ #slideshow:hover .pause` indicate?

**------------------EDIT AFTER [Brian Stephens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806970/1705922)----------------------**

For **Question 2**) i still can't understand what is the meaning of that a hover state must be preceded by an ID with the `:target` pseudo class, In general in css the precedence is about elements disposition in the code but in this case it looks like it's about events rather : does it mean that the hyperlink targeting the `#sl_play` must be activated first and then the hover should occur on the `#slideshow` for that the rule could be valid ? If the precedence is about events so the precedence in code won't matter anymore ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question #1**: Does the first combination `#slideshow:hover .pause` translate to "Select all elements with the class name pause that are descendants of the element with an ID of slideshow"?

**Answer:** Yes, it's a descendant selector, which doesn't specify that it has to be a child; it could be further down. Keep in mind, it also specifies the hover state.

**Question #2**: What does `#sl_play:target ~ #slideshow:hover .pause` indicate?

**Answer:** This uses a general sibling connector. `#slideshow:hover` must be preceded by `#sl_play:target`, but not necessarily immediately. It must be a later sibling.

Here's a good article explaining all the variations of child and sibling selectors: [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Comment: For Question #2 i still can't understand what is the meaning of that a hover state must be preceded by an ID with the :target pseudo class, In general in css the precedance is about elements disposition in the code but in this case it looks like it's about events rather : does it means that the hyperlink targeting the #sl_play must be activated first and then the hover should occur on the #slideshow for that the rule could be valide ? sur i don't think so but why not shortly use #sl_play:target ?

Comment: @Bardelman: They are completely separate. The selector simply expects that one element should match `:target` while the other element should match `:hover`. If either of these elements doesn't match the pseudo-class as given by the selector, the selector will not match. As another example, it's just like `#id.class1 ~ .pause` - if the element doesn't have "class1", then the selector would not match.

Comment: @Bardelman: Why would you use both? That depends entirely on how the CSS is expected to work. Maybe it only works if each of those two conditions is met in that specific order.